# HBase - how can I use bash to get the HBase Master address?

Tags: bash, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to write a little automated status routine for my cluster.  Basically, I am writing a little shell script that will query all the nodes, checking for various metrics (kind of like Ganglia would give me.. but I can't use that... long story).  This done, other than for HBase.   For all other servers (NN, JT, ZKs, etc.) I can look in configuration files and know the hostname.  The HBase master, however, is not listed anywhere.  It is in the '/hbase/master' znode.

My question.. how can I get that hostname just from bash?  I have been trying things like 'zkCli.sh -server myzoo << get /hbase/master', and similar, but so far, I am coming up empty.

Bottom line, is that I want one shell script that can access all of my main servers.  HBase is the only one I am having trouble with.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: good addition.. thanks Jayan K.

Comment: what is the problem with zkCli.sh -server myzoo << get /hbase/master

Comment: the zkCli.sh -server myzoo << get /hbase/master does not really seem to do anything.  Puts me at a '>' prompt... but does not give me any thing helpful.

Comment: so, I was able to get closer by putting my commands in a text file and running zkCli.sh -server myzoo < input.txt.  The input file (input.txt) has two lines.  The first line performs a get (get /hbase/master) and the second line does a quit.  While this works, it is still not optimal.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

According to the usage string, we should be able to just do

```
zkCli.sh -server myzoo get /hbase/master
```

Even if that doesn't work, we can do without input.txt:

```
zkCli.sh -server myzoo <<EOF
get /hbase/master
quit
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

we can have "hbase.master" property in hbase-site.xml file, and from there you can pick it just like other processes.

Comment: We don't have that.  We have the hbase.zookeeper.quorum specified instead.  So, I need to figure out how to get the hbase master node given just that.